# Unable to run Tensorflow 2 with matplotlib

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib

I have installed matplotlib in the tensorflow environment (Jupyter notebook) using conda install command. There is no error in the compilation. But while running, I am encountering a message " Dead Kernel" and the program terminates. The other programs without matplotlib are executed smoothly. Not able to figure out the cause and its remedy.

Comment: Please could you give more info on the environment - OS, and versions of packages installed, and how they were installed

Comment: You will also want to include the console messages that are being spit out somewhere, usually the shell where you started your notebook.   Finally, what did you do to get the kernel to hang.   "But while running" is vague

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the "Conda" or the "Jupyter Notebook" again :)